# Is it possible to use filestack in cordova

Tags: cordova, filepicker.io

I'm using filestack to upload files, but just realized it doesn't seem to work in cordova, though it works fine in safari mobile.

Is there a workaround or recommended solution?

Comment: What does filestack support say?

Comment: They haven't said anything helpful yet.